# How to make responsive layout in android xml?

Tags: android, android-layout

i'm trying to create a simple layout which is contain images. Here is what i do for now

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_marginStart="2mm"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="27mm"
        android:layout_height="30mm"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the result in 2 device(s)

In pixel 2 api

[image]

and here is is nexus 4

[image]

The images are inside RecyclerView. Here is how i set it up in my fragment

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
myListArrival.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

as you can see in pixel 2 , there is almost half of next picture showing up instead up in nexus 4. **Maybe** it's a margin.

Btw, i'm using android studio emulator

I'm using MM because this http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/06/android-units-of-measurements.html.

So my question is, how can i make the image size and margin are same in two devices ? how can i achieve it ?

An Update using DP.

And now, i'm only showing 2 pictures now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"

         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

result

Nexus 4

[image]

Pixel 2

[image]

Comment: try using dp instead of mm

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך i'm trying using DP please check my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Thanks to everyone who answer the question. I already get what i want to achieve (At least it's better). Here is what i do.

First i change

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
myListArrival.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

to

```
mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
myListArrival.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
```

Second change is in my XML. here is the changes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout

android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the last change is in my parentlayout .

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearHot"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:text="Our Products"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/product_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

so here is the result

[image]

Left side is nexus and the right side is pixel 2

Answer (score 2):

> I have Used the constraint layout to Implement your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is never use hardCoding to set any widgets use match_parent and wrap_content instead of integers.
If you want to use particular height and width somewhere then use density pixel(dp) instead of mm and cm and use (sp) for text.

Answer (score 0):

Static height width will not support in all devices.

Change imageview width and height as "match_parent" and try scaleType to fit in screen

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/image"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way that android recommends is to create a separate layout file for layouts for different screen sizes.
Please check this out
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_height="1dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ww1"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:id="@+id/walpaper1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```